# How can I stop letting other clutter / expand my namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Suppose, if I have a `namespace` in one header file. I don't want that people should be able to expand it to other files. Is it possible in C++ ?

```
//N.h
namespace N {
 //...
}

//Other.h
#include"N.h"

namespace N {    // <--- don't allow this
  void foo () {}  
}
```

[Note: Asking this for knowledge and curiosity. Because, have heard many times that one should not expand `std`.]

Comment: Is there a practical example where this would actually be useful? Why do you care if others add things to your namespace?

Comment: It's not possible to prohibit this. Where are you running into this issue?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, you can't do this in C++, and I don't see any practical reason for it either.

You can wrap your code into a class instead of a namespace; since a class declaration cannot be spread over several headers, others cannot add to it.

But again, I don't see why you think this is a problem, and I'd be curious to see an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can only *ask* people to behave, not force them. Perhaps you can try this:

```
namespace milind
{
    namespace Private
    {
        // Please don't add stuff to my private namespace

        ... Important implementation details goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class with all statics instead of a namespace to simulate the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Found one way. I can encapsulate the `namespace` inside another dummy type of `namespace` and then use it. To avoid verbosity, we can use an alias to the existing `namespace`.

i.e.

```
//N.h
namespace DUMMY_ {  // <--- put a dummy outer namespace
namespace N {
 //...
}
}
namespace N = DUMMY_::N; // alias the name to the original name

//Other.h
#include"N.h"

namespace N {    // <--- error !!
  void foo () {}  
}
```

**Edit**: With above solution it's less likely that people would expand `namespace N`. However, as @Charles comment, still `DUMMY_` is visible to the reader. Which means one can still do like:

```
namespace DUMMY_ {
  namespace N {  // ok
    void foo () {}
  }
}
```

So only way remains to prohibit the undesired expansion is by replacing:

```
namespace N = DUMMY_::N;
```

with,

```
#define N DUMMY_::N
```

This will work as per expected; but we enter the region of macros.

Comment: What's stopping people doing the usual _and correct_ syntax of `namespace DUMMY_ { namespace N { /* more stuff */ } }` ? `DUMMY_` must be visible and known to clients. I don't see how this addresses the issue posed in the question.

Comment: `#undef N` newline `namespace DUMMY_ { namespace N { /* more stuff */ } }` newline `#define N DUMMY_::N` .